# Escaping quotes when using SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, quoting

I'm trying to build a simple deployment script for my PHP apps. I know there are several tools for this job (Capistrano, Phing, etc.) but they seem like a lot of work for my simple deployment routine.

I use [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) to avoid typing my password over and over again. But after uploading my compressed installer, I need to ssh into the server and run some commands. One of which is sed. So, quotes are breaking my script. It's something like this:

```
sshpass -p foo ssh user@host "
   cd /www/htdocs/foo/bar 
   echo 'Untar and remove installer'
   tar -zxf install.tar.gz

   sed "s/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');" index.php > tmp && mv tmp index.php
   sed "s/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');/" admin/index.php > tmp && mv tmp admin/index.php

"
```

As you can see, I use double-quotes to start my SSH statements, but I also need to use them on sed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escaping the internal quote marks is the normal way. Does this not work?

```
sshpass -p foo ssh user@host "
cd /www/htdocs/foo/bar
echo 'Untar and remove installer'
tar -zxf install.tar.gz

sed \"s/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');\" index.php > tmp && mv tmp index.php
sed \"s/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');/\" admin/index.php > tmp && mv tmp admin/index.php

"
```

Answer (score 2):

Can a here-document be used instead?:

```
sshpass -p foo ssh user@host <<DATA
   cd /www/htdocs/foo/bar 
   echo 'Untar and remove installer'
   tar -zxf install.tar.gz

   sed "s/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');" index.php > tmp && mv tmp index.php
   sed "s/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');/define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');/" admin/index.php > tmp && mv tmp admin/index.php
DATA
```

Comment: also, use `<<"DATA"` if you don't want variable expansion inside the here document

Comment: This works, but throws a warning:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.