# How to change parameter in a file, only if the file exists and the parameter is not already set?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, tee

```
#!/bin/bash
# See if registry is set to expire updates
filename=hostnames
> test.log

PARAMETER=Updates
FILE=/etc/.properties

CODE=sudo if [ ! -f $FILE] && grep $PARAMETER $FILE; then echo "File found, parameter not found."
#CODE=grep $PARAMETER $FILE || sudo tee -a /etc/.properties <<< $PARAMETER

while read -r -a line
do
        hostname=${line//\"}
        echo $hostname":" >> test.log
        #ssh -n -t -t $hostname "$CODE" >> test.log
        echo $CODE;
done < "$filename"

exit
```

I want to set "Updates 30" in /etc/.properties on about 50 servers if:

- The file exists (not all servers have the software installed)
- The parameter  "Updates" is not already set in the file (e.g. in case of multiple runs)

I am a little puzzled so far how, because I am not sure if this can be done in 1 line of bash code. The rest of the script works fine.

Comment: If the file works fine, what about deploying it to all the servers? A simple loop can work fine for this.

Comment: This is two separate issues: [Adding a line to a file](http://serverfault.com/questions/39303/how-to-add-line-to-system-configuration-file-with-sudo) and [escaping arguments of an `ssh` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621777/escaping-quotes-when-using-ssh)

Comment: This might help you out for passing via ssh http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/181221-bash-script-execute-command-remote-servers-using-ssh.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what i think would be a solution for you. Like explained in this article http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/181221-bash-script-execute-command-remote-servers-using-ssh.html

invoke the script which contains the commands that you want to be executed at the remote server

Code script 1:

```
while read -r -a line
do
    ssh ${line} "bash -s" < script2

done < "$filename"
```

To replace a line in a text file, you can use sed (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/)
Code script 2:

```
PARAMETER=Updates
FILE=/etc/.properties
NEWPARAMETER=Updates ###(What you want to write there)

if [ ! -f $FILE] && grep $PARAMETER $FILE; then exit

sed -i 's/$PARAMETER/$NEWPARAMETER/g' $FILE
```

So, I'm not certain this covers all your use case, I hope this helps you out if there is anything feel free to ask!