# How to pass commands as arguments to ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting

My need is to make this command work:

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container /bin/bash -c \" psql -d crawl-configuration -c 'select * from schema_version'\"
```

But the result indicates that * is expanded by the shell and all matching files are passed as arguments to the psql command. So I searched how to protect the command from being expanded, but without success.

My experimentations gave me the following results.

A - The following command works, TOTO is displayed on my shell

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container /bin/bash -c \"echo TOTO\"
```

B - The following command doesn't work, a blank line is displayed on my shell

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container /bin/bash -c "echo TOTO"
```

C - This works, the result of ls is displayed. I don't understand why it works but not case B ?

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container /bin/bash -c "ls"
```

D - This works, I have the expected result

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container /bin/bash -c \" psql -d crawl-configuration -c \'select version from schema_version\' \"
```

E - Execution of this command on the host without passing by ssh works

```
sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container /bin/bash -c " psql -d crawl-configuration -c 'select * from schema_version'"
```

What is the solution to make my first command work ?

Comment: In B, `echo TOTO` is passed as a single word which is unlikely to be a valid command. To pass an asterisk to a remote command you can try the following steps: a) the asterisk itself should be quoted (which it is when inside single quotes); b) put enough (quoted) backslashes before it to further quote it remotely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Older dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621777/escaping-quotes-when-using-ssh

Comment: @BenjaminW., thank you; added that to the list as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this:

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 \
  "sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container \
  /bin/bash -c \"psql -d crawl-configuration -c 'select * from schema_version'\""
```

Double quote the whole command to be executed by ssh, then escape double quotes within the command.

Alternatively, use a here-doc:

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -T -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no wsuser@192.168.0.100 <<-'EOF'
    sudo docker exec -u postgres postgres-container \
    /bin/bash -c "psql -d crawl-configuration -c 'select * from schema_version'"
EOF
```

No quoting needed because of the quoted `'EOF'` delimiter. The `-T` disables allocation of a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: The first solution worked for me. Tanks a lot.